# How to generate apk from a react native project I inherited

Tags: react-native

I inherited a react native project, the original programmers generated an apk for android, but they are not available anymore.
In the project I see react-native.config.js, package.json and an android folder with gradlew.

For the moment I'd like just to generate apk for android...but I don't know where to start...

Answer (score 3):

You can create an assemble release following these commands. Open up a command line / terminal within you project and run the following commands.

Install node modules.

```
npm install
```

Link dependencies.

```
react-native link
```

Create the metro bundle.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Change the directory to android.

```
cd android
```

Clean the Gradle.

```
gradlew clean
```

Create the assemble release.

```
gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

You can find the APK in

> PROJECT_PATH\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release

Comment: I did some "basic first" like npm install and npm install -g react-native-cli. I got an error "error Unable to resolve module `react-native-tab-view`" which I solved with npm install react-native-tab-view. Now after gradlew clean, I try to build assembleRelease but I get Task 'bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' not found in root project...I think assembleReleas task is missing

Comment: with gradlew tasks I see: assemble, assembleAndroidTest, build, buildDependents, buildNeeded...

Comment: the task assemble and assembleAndroidTest build successfully but I don't see any apk. Gradlew build fails with this Task :@react-native-community_async-storage:lint FAILED

Comment: Hi @ARisseu, I have updated the APK file path. If the assemble build succeeded you can find the APK (app-release.apk) in the given path.

Comment: npm installing is also added to resolve missing dependencies.

Comment: but I don't have the task "assembleRelease". I have just the task "assemble" that builds successfully, but doesn't create any apk anywhere in under project directory. I don't even have that apk/release directory

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

- perform `npm start` in your root-dir of project
- run `npm i` in same root-dir of project
- can perform `react-native link` in root-dir location
- now `cd android`
- now `gradlew assembleRelease`

it will generate your .apk file at `project_name/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release`

Comment: everybody seems to have this task "assembleRelease" but the only tasks that I see are: assemble, assembleAndroidTest, build, buildDependented, buildNeeded...They either build successfully without creating any apk anywhere or fail with Task :@react-native-community_async-storage:lint FAILED